# Objects in core data share the same information and don't fully delete

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have an app that uses core data to store two UITables of information. When the a collection row is tapped it shows a table that has pictures. The option to add a picture or collection is indicated with the +. When ever a new picture object is inserted  `[collection addPhotoObject:photo];`  and you navigate to another collection it has the same row there. Even when all the collections are deleted and a new one is added, it has the same info as the old one(s). How can this be prevented?

Has this been encountered before? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes upon this in the future I hope this helps answer their question.

After several trials I found my problem. I was not populating my data correctly. All I had to do was `return [collection.indexCard count];` in `-tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section`. I also had to make sure that whenever I added or deleted an object I use some form of `[self.tableview reloadData]`.

P.S. If a change is made (and with any core data) delete the app from the simulator to reset everything.